# Как обрабатывать ошибки в jest?

Tags: javascript, jest

Я хочу обработать ошибку в моей функции, но тест не проходит, так как выдает ошибку, что переданный аргумент должен быть строкой

```
const reverseString = str => {
  if (typeof str !== "string") {
    throw new Error("Not a string");
  }

  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

test("Check on reverse string", () => {
  expect(reverseString(0)).toThrowError();
});
```

Как я могу выполнить тест, обработав ошибку в функции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам нужно обернуть в функцию:

```
test("Check on reverse string", () => {
  expect(()=>{reverseString(0)}).toThrowError();
});
```